# For resnet50 model, how do I extract a new model from it starting from a particular layer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, resnet

I am trying to split resnet50 model in two parts in pytorch. I want to split the model by a layer in the bottleneck unit, so I couldn't use index to split it. The reason is that the model layers are a bunch of `nn.sequntial` units.

I used `torchvision.models.feature_extraction.create_feature_extractor` to extract the former part of resnet50, but I couldn't use it for extracting the latter half since create_feature_extractor creates a new model by copying the original model up to a certain layer. Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/5508